# What is the difference between hadoop job -kill job_id and yarn application -kill application_id

Tags: hadoop, hive

What is the difference between `hadoop job -kill job_id` and `yarn application -kill application_id`? Whether the job_id and application_id represent/refer to same task?

Answer (score 14):

`hadoop job -kill job_id` and `yarn application -kill application_id` both command is used to kill a job running on Hadoop.

If you are using MapReduce Version1(MR V1) and you want to kill a job running on Hadoop, then you can use `hadoop job -kill job_id` to kill a job and it will kill all jobs( both running and queued).

In MapReduce Version2(MR V2 or YARN) when you submit a MapReduce job, It process through a application master and hence the job called application.There could be multiple task running within a application. If you want to kill a application then you can use `yarn application -kill application_id` command to kill the application. It will kill all running and queued jobs under the application.

If you want to kill a task in YARN then you can use `hadoop job -kill-task <task-id>` to kill a particular task in YARN

This [link](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.3/bk_using-apache-hadoop/content/running_mapreduce_examples_on_yarn.html) will be useful to understand application and job in YARN.

Comment: ..is there any way to prevent a user from killing job of another user.

Comment: Wanted to update for latest version its changed to this command - `mapred job -kill-task <attempt_id>
`

Comment: `yarn application -kill application_id` working fine

Answer (score 4):

Application_id is the ID associated with Application master. Both IDs are one and the same(will have same ID value) except for the prefixes **application_** and **job_** before the ID.

Both represent the same job only!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use YARN version of kill command, the resource manager kills the AM without AM's knowledge so it will not generate history. If you use hadoop job -kill job_id the killing process goes through the AM and it will allow to generate history